# Search String Algorithm in Table

Tags: search-algorithms, substrings, longest-common-substring

For a given database table:

```
DB

id   w1,  w2,  w3,  w4,    v
1    A                    X1
2    B                    X2
3    A    B               Y0
3    A    B    C          Y1
4    C                    X3
5    D                    X4
6    B    C    D          Y2
7    C    D    F          Y3
8    C    D    G          Y4
9    E                    X5
```

There exists an input with expected output based on a string search/match on the table. What we are trying to do is match the input with a combination of rows from the database. The only portion of the row that we use for matching is from `w1` to `w4`. We then use the `v` column to identify the row. So, for example, the input string `E` would produce output `X5`, while input `A, B` would produce output `Y0`. In the case that there is no exact match, we want the elements closer to the front of the list to represent as long a string as possible. For example, with input `A, B, C, D, E` we could match a number of ways, notably `Y1, X4, X5`, `X1, Y2, X5`. We prefer the former, because `A, B, C` (from `Y1`) is longer than `A` (from `X1`). We want the first item in the output to represent as long a string as possible, and only when two potential outputs have the same length for the initial item do we try to get the longest second item we can.

## Example 2:

input = `A, B, C, D, F`

**expected_output =>** `Y0, Y3`

### Explanation:

We would like to find `A, B, C, D, F`, but there is no match.

Likewise, we would match `A, B, C, D` if we could, but we cannot.

We do find `Y1` is a match for `A, B, C`, so we use that. Our partial solution is `Y1`.

Now we look for `D, F`, but we don't find it.

We find `X4` matches `D`, so our partial solution is `Y1, X4`.

Next we look for `F` but then there is no match. At this point we backtrack until we find a solution that does work. We take `X4` off our solution and look for a better match for `D`, but there is no other way to match it, and we can't match a shorter substring, because that would be empty.

We take `Y1` off our solution (now it is empty) and look for another way to match `A, B, C`. There is no other way, so we look for `A, B`, which we find with `Y0`. Our partial solution is `Y0`.

Now we search for the remainder of the input, `C, D, F` and we find it with `Y3`. Our solution is `Y0, Y3`.

**Question:**

What algorithms could I use or learn to be able to solve this efficiently?

What is the pseudocode or high level overview of how to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. Could you give a clear explanation of what you want this algorithm to do?

Comment: Basically you just need to check if there is a match on 1 of the rows in the table. But you have to do it in a way that it searches first for the longest string.

Comment: "I am trying to solve this problem efficiently" I can't understand your description of the problem.

Comment: Can you please describe what is the problem you are trying to solve. Worked examples aren't enough: what is the actual problem? Why, when ABCDE and ABCD fail, do you move on to ABC rather than BCDE?

Comment: I still don't understand what problem you are trying to solve.  You need to specify the inputs, the outputs, and precisely what property the correct output must satisfy.  You can't specify an algorithm by listing examples.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Is it better now?

Comment: @Raphael No. The problem is still mostly described using examples, though some cases now have a specification. Why does input AB produce Y0 and not Y1? Am I always supposed to go for an exact match of the template versus the template being a substring of the record?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some code in Python to solve this problem. Python is designed to be very readable. There is a plaintext explanation of the algorithm below to help you understand what's going on. I am treating the database as an array indexable by its columns and rows.

```
def find_match(db, input_string):
    if input_string == '':
        return list()
    matches = list()
    length = 0
    for row in db:
        for col in [w1, w2, w3, w4]:
            if len(input_string) == length:
                return list(row[v]) # we found a match!
            if row[col] != input_string[length]:
                length = 0
                break
            length += 1
        if length == 0:
            continue
        if len(input_string) == length:
            return list(row[v]) # we found a match!
        matches.append((length, row[v]))
    matches.sort(reverse=True) # this puts longest matches first 
    for length, match in matches:
        solution = find_match(db, input_string[length:]) 
# input_string[length:] means the input_string from index length till the end.
        if solution != []:
            return list(match) + solution
    return list()
```

## Explanation:

This is a recursive algorithm to match the input. What it does is it loops over all rows in the database and finds all the ones that could be part of a match. If it finds anything that is a complete match, then it returns it immediately (there's no point going any further once you've found a solution.)

Then it sorts this list of potential matches so that the longest ones are evaluated first. It loops through these sorted matches and calls the `find_match` function using the portion of the input string that still needs to be matched, if that match is the one to be used. In this way, you are evaluating the longest matches first, as you requested.

## A step-by-step example (Example 2 from your question):

```
DB

id   w1,  w2,  w3,  w4,    v
1    A                    X1
2    B                    X2
3    A    B               Y0
3    A    B    C          Y1
4    C                    X3
5    D                    X4
6    B    C    D          Y2
7    C    D    F          Y3
8    C    D    G          Y4
9    E                    X5
```

`input_string: [A, B, C, D, F]`

`input_string` is not empty, so we construct `matches` as an empty list. This is the list of rows that could be part of the final solution (they must entirely match the input string from the beginning until they run out of characters)

We loop over the rows, and find the following potential matches:
`X1 (A); Y0 (A, B); Y1 (A, B, C)`

We add them to the list as a tuple containing their length and the `v` that corresponds to them. This way we will be able to make sure we check the longest matches first. `matches` looks like this once we finish iterating over the `db`:
`[(1, X1), (2, Y0), (3, Y1)]`

Next we sort the list using the length as the key so the longest matches are first:
`[(3, Y1), (2, Y0), (1, X1)]`

Now we iterate over the matches, and try to find a solution using each one. Because we are calling the function recursively, it could be a long time between checking each match, depending on the length of the input string that still needs to be matched.

The first row we try to find a solution with is the first element in `matches`: `Y1 (A, B, C)`. We call `find_match(db, [D, F])` using `[D, F]` as the input string because that is the portion that still needs to be matched if we use `Y1 (A, B, C)`. We can easily find the input string because we have the length (3, in this case) and so we take `input_string` from its 3rd index on:

```
A, B, C, D, F
0, 1, 2, 3, 4
X  X  X  D, F
```

`input_string: [D, F]`

we loop over the rows and find only one match: `X4 (D)`

Our list of matches is `[(1, X4)]`, so we call `find_match(db, [F])`

`input_string: [F]`

we loop over the rows and find 0 matches, so matches is `[]` and when we iterate over it, we immediately continue on to the next block of code which tells us to `return []`. This is our way of saying we didn't find any match.

Now we go back to when `input_string` was `[D, F]`. We set `solution` equal to `[]`, because that's what we just returned. Our only potential match was `(X4, D)`, which we just checked, so now we are done iterating over the potential matches. Because we couldn't find any match with `[D, F]` as the input string we return `[]` as well.

Now we go back to when `[A, B, C, D, F]` was the input string and we had just finished trying to match `Y1`. We continue iterating over matches (`[(3, Y1), (2, Y0), (1, X1)]`). We call `find_match(db, [C, D, F])` using `Y0 (A, B)` as the match.

`input_string: [C, D, F]`

We loop over the rows and we would get `X3 (C); Y3 (C, D, F); Y4 (C, D, G)` as our matches, but once we find that `Y3 (C, D, F)` exactly matches the input string, we go ahead and return `[Y3]`

Now we go back to when `[A, B, C, D, F]` was the input string and we were just using `Y1 (A, B, C)` as the match. At this point we see that we did find a match (the function returned `[Y3]`) and we add `Y1` to it so that we have the full match: `[Y1, Y3]`. We return that and the function is done executing.

In the part of the function that compares the row with the input string, there is a little bit of bounds checking to make sure we only take as many characters from the row as it has, and we don't try to match the input string with a row that is longer than it is, but I didn't bother elaborating on that because it never came up in this example.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!  We'd prefer that you explain the main ideas (rather than just copy-pasting a bunch of code with no explanation).  Might you consider editing the answer to add this?  Also, if you understood what the question was asking, might you consider editing the question to make it clearer what problem Raven wants solved?

Comment: copy-paste? I wrote the algorithm myself, thank you very much. I'll add an explanation of what I did. I tried to explain along the way with comments, but I'll give a broader explanation as well. I already edited the question, it needs to be peer reviewed.

Comment: @JonMcClung By copy-paste it was rather "copied from your own editor / environmnent, where you produced the code into the answer". Not everybody speaks Python, but everyone would like to read your algorithm hence the explanation would be very nice - like plain text with idea.